# Error with PHP SDK (Windows)

Tags: google-app-engine

Having trouble with PHP SDK (Windows) - it installs OK but when I use the launcher the **"Hello World"** script runs and outputs **"Hello World"**
**but**
 with the error message:

```
"chdir(): Invalid argument (errno 22) in C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\php\setup.php on line 42"
```

I tried re-installing but since it is kinda working I'm not sure what to do next - is there a problem in this file  (like there was in v. 1.8.1) ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you happen to put your "Hello World" app on a network drive or on some funky path?